# Excel macro changing the OS date in Windows XP

Tags: excel, vba, windows, date

I built a macro to update dates on a master sheet in Excel 2010 VBA.  However every time I run the macro my OS (Windows XP) date is changing to whatever date the macro put on the master sheet.

For example I updated 12/1/2018 on the master sheet, the date on my task bar changed to 12/1/2018 and I received calendar notifications for every recurring meeting on my calendar up to 12/1/2018.

```
Sub UploadComplete()
'Uploads the date marker at contract on master

'Set up the array Contracts which will house the new contracts to be uploaded
Dim Contracts() As String
Dim size As Integer
Dim N As Integer
Dim R As Integer

'This sets up the value for N as the number (namely the row number) at the end of the
N = Worksheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Identifies which column to add the marker to
R = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("F2"), Worksheets("Update").Range("E14:G263"), 3, False)

'Determine size of array and store it into variable size
size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Update").Columns(1))

'Having counted size can redim the array
ReDim Contracts(size)

'Insert the values in column A into the array
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To size
    Contracts(i) = Worksheets("Update").Range("A1").Offset(i)
Next i

'Takes each value in the array and adds it to the end of the master list using N
For i = LBound(Contracts) To UBound(Contracts)
    Worksheets("Master").Range("A" & N).Value = Contracts(i)
    N = N + 1
Next i

'Remove the duplicates from the master tab based on the first column namely
'column A
Worksheets("Master").Range("A1:ZZ1000000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

'Remove blank rows from Master
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("Master").Range("A1:A1000000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
rng.EntireRow.Delete

'Find the contract from the imput grab the terminated date and put it into the master
For i = LBound(Contracts) To UBound(Contracts)

    If Contracts(i) <> "" Then

        Set rgFound = Worksheets("Update").Range("A2:A1000000").Find(Contracts(i), , , xlWhole)

        Date = rgFound.Offset(, 1).Value

        Set rgFill = Worksheets("Master").Range("A:A").Find(Contracts(i))

        rgFill.Offset(, R) = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyy")
        rgFill.Offset(, R).Value = Date                 '?CHANGING DATE ON OS?

    End If

Next i

'Remove blank rows from Master
Set rng = Worksheets("Master").Range("A1:A1000000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
rng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the line that changes the system date (see [Date function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278644.aspx)):

```
Date = rgFound.Offset(, 1).Value
```

you should assign the current value to a local variable and then only read from this: e.g.

```
Dim CurrentDate
CurrentDate = Date    ' CurrentDate contains the current system date.
```

Comment: Should have realized Date was a function, I was just trying to use it as a variable.  Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: You should take a look at [OPTION EXPLICIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx). This can help a to avoid such a problem.